# C++ Multimap - check for duplicates before insert a new value to multimap?

Tags: c++, multithreading

How can I check for duplicates before insert a new value to multimap in C++?

Comment: First of all ; have you tried anything yourself before asking here? Secondly, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have to check the multimap before insert a new value in order to make a vector that contains only values of the duplicates.

Comment: If you don't want duplicates why do you use a multimap?

Comment: because I've to multimap <file path, size> and when I have duplicated size -> compare md5 hash for this files in order to find duplicate files in directory.

Comment: This was tagged "multithreading" which makes me very nervous.  If there is a multithreading issue here, you'll need some sort of mutex protection to make sure everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Multimap.html

A multimap has a `find` method you can use to check if your key already exists.